# Error: Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-loop, react-select, react-props

I am receiving this error with my React project:

```
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly 
calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits 
the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

I do not know what is causing the infinite loop. I am using the react-select drop-down library. Maybe it has something to do with the library thinking the value is constantly changing. I am not sure. Any help is great and much appreciated thanks.

Here is the parent class code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./App.css";
import { Grid, Row, Col, PageHeader } from "react-bootstrap";
import AdvDrop from "./AdvDrop";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    childsName: null
  };

  handleName = newName => {
    this.setState({ childsName: newName });
    console.log("callback called");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <PageHeader>
          WALI <small>Prototype</small>
        </PageHeader>
        {console.log("parent re-rendered")}
        <AdvDrop
          name={this.state.childsName}
          onNameChanged={this.handleName()}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And the child class code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import "./AdvDrop.css";
import "./App.js";

const options = [
  { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
  { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
  { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
];

class AdvDrop extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedOption: this.props.name
  };

  handleChange = selectedOption => {
    {
      /*this.setState({ selectedOption });*/
    }
    this.props.onNameChanged(selectedOption);
    console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
  };

  render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {console.log("child re-rendered")}
        <Select
          className="station"
          value={selectedOption}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          options={options}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AdvDrop;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are *invoking* the `handleName` function directly on render by writing `this.handleName()`. Just give the function reference to `onNameChanged` instead.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    childsName: null
  };

  handleName = newName => {
    this.setState({ childsName: newName });
    console.log("callback called");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <PageHeader>
          WALI <small>Prototype</small>
        </PageHeader>
        {console.log("parent re-rendered")}
        <AdvDrop name={this.state.childsName} onNameChanged={this.handleName} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```